# How do I use dplyr::across with a multi-argument function on a grouped data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, moving-average, across

I want to compute a weighted moving average across multiple columns, using the same weights for each column. The weighted moving average shall be computed per group (in contrast to [using `dplyr::across` with functions with more than one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329706/using-dplyracross-with-functions-with-more-than-one-argument)).

In the example below, the grouping should make the weighted moving average "reset" every year, yielding missing values for the first two observations of each year.

How do I make this work?

```r
library(tidyverse)

weighted.filter <- function(x, wt, filter, ...) {
  filter <- filter / sum(filter)
  stats::filter(x * wt, filter, ...) / stats::filter(wt, filter, ...)
}

economics %>%
  group_by(year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(across(
    c(pce, psavert, uempmed),
    list("moving_average_weighted" = weighted.filter),
    wt = pop, filter = rep(1, 3), sides = 1
  ))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 12.
#> ℹ Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
#> ℹ Input `..1` must be size 12 or 1, not 6.
#> ℹ The error occurred in group 2: year = 1968.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Try

```r
economics %>%
  group_by(year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(across(
    c(pce, psavert, uempmed),
    list("moving_average_weighted" =
      ~ weighted.filter(., wt = pop, filter = rep(1, 3), sides = 1))
  ))
# # A tibble: 574 x 10
# # Groups:   year [49]
#    date         pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy  year pce_moving_average_w~ psavert_moving_avera~ uempmed_moving_avera~
#    <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>                 <dbl>                 <dbl>                 <dbl>
#  1 1967-07-01  507. 198712    12.6     4.5     2944  1967                   NA                   NA                   NA   
#  2 1967-08-01  510. 198911    12.6     4.7     2945  1967                   NA                   NA                   NA   
#  3 1967-09-01  516. 199113    11.9     4.6     2958  1967                  511.                  12.4                  4.60
#  4 1967-10-01  512. 199311    12.9     4.9     3143  1967                  513.                  12.5                  4.73
#  5 1967-11-01  517. 199498    12.8     4.7     3066  1967                  515.                  12.5                  4.73
#  6 1967-12-01  525. 199657    11.8     4.8     3018  1967                  518.                  12.5                  4.80
#  7 1968-01-01  531. 199808    11.7     5.1     2878  1968                   NA                   NA                   NA   
#  8 1968-02-01  534. 199920    12.3     4.5     3001  1968                   NA                   NA                   NA   
#  9 1968-03-01  544. 200056    11.7     4.1     2877  1968                  536.                  11.9                  4.57
# 10 1968-04-01  544  200208    12.3     4.6     2709  1968                  541.                  12.1                  4.40
# # ... with 564 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But why does my attempt fail and yours work?

Comment: Not sure exactly why, but if you `debug` your function and run it: first group `length(x)` is 6, `length(wt)` is 6, good; second group, `length(x)` is 12, `length(wt)` is 6, the same 6 as the first group ... bad. I would have assumed that `wt=pop` would have brought in each group's values of `pop, but apparently that isn't happening here with your call ... but with my call, it does (6 and 6, then 12 and 12, etc)